# Como escrever o nome da letra grega rô?

Tags: ortografia

Existe um algoritmo de fatoração chamado "algoritmo $\rho$ de John Pollard".  Em língua inglesa, é comum ver a palavra rho empregada nesse caso.  Acredito que "h" tenha sido usada pra lembrar ao anglo-saxão que a pronúncia do "o" é fechada.

Mas e em português?  Como devo escrever o nome da letra $\rho$?

Não posso meramente exibir a letra grega porque quero usá-la em títulos e resumos de documentos, onde não se deve adicionar símbolos especiais além de palavras da língua corrente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como se pronuncia: **rô** (ou "ró", em pt-PT).

Vide [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A1) ou [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/r%C3%B4):

> rô
>   sm.
>
> 1. A 17a letra do alfabeto grego. Corresponde ao r latino (x, x).
>
> [F.: Do gr. rhô, pelo lat. rho.]

Comment: Perfeito.  Nem considerei olhar o dicionário porque nem passou pela minha cabeça que fosse encontrar tal vocábulo por lá.  Incrível que vinha escrevendo "rô" informalmente --- sem nunca achar que estava correta a escrita.  Muito obrigado!